# How to solve $ 2^{\vert x + 1 \vert} - 2^x = \vert 2^x - 1\vert + 1 $ for $ x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I am new to modulus and inequalities , I came across this problem:

$ 2^{\vert x + 1 \vert} - 2^x = \vert 2^x - 1\vert + 1 $ for $ x $

How to find $ x $ ?

Comment: Have you tried splitting into cases?

Comment: @Arthur yes, i know that much

Comment: Then what's stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider three cases:.

i) $\bf x\leq -1$. Then $x\leq -1$, $2^x< 1$, and the equation becomes
$\frac{1}{2}2^{-x} - 2^x = 1- 2^x + 1$, that is $2^{-x}=4$ which implies that $x=-2\leq -1$.

ii) $\bf -1<x<0$. Then $x>-1$, $2^x< 1$, and the equation becomes $2^x=2\cdot 2^{x} - 2^x = 1- 2^x + 1=2-2^x$, that is $2^x=1$ which is impossible for $-1<x<0$.

iii) $\bf 0\leq x$. Then $x>-1$, $2^x\geq 1$, and the equation becomes $2^x=2^x$ which holds for all $x\geq 0$.

Hence the complete set of solutions is $\{-2\}\cup [0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Sir, why in ii) $ 2^x < 1 $

Comment: @RaviPrakash Because $2^x\in (2^0;2^{-1}), \text{whose maximum value is } 2^0=1$.

Comment: @Ravi Prakash Because in ii) $x<0$

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder $ [ 2^0 ; 2^{-1}] $ or $ ( 2^0 ; 2^{-1}) $

Answer (score 1):

If $x\geq 0$, then

- $|x+1| = x+1$
- $|2^x-1| = 2^x-1$

So the equation becomes

$$2^{x+1}-2^x=2^x-1+1\\
2^{x+1} - 2\cdot 2^x=0\\
2^{x+1}-2^{x+1}=0\\
0=0$$

so it is always true.

---

There are two more cases to do: $-1\leq x<0$ and $x<-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :divide into cases.
$$\forall x\geq 0 \to R.H.S=L.H.S \\2^{\vert x + 1 \vert} - 2^x = \vert 2^x - 1\vert + 1 \to \\2^{x+1}-2^x=2^x-1+1\\2(2^x)-2^x=2^x \checkmark\\ x\in[0,\infty)$$

Then $$for \space -\leq x\leq0 \to 2^{\vert x + 1 \vert} - 2^x = \vert 2^x - 1\vert + 1 \implies x=-2\\
\to 2^{x + 1 } - 2^x =  1-2^x + 1 \implies x=-2\\2^x=2-2^x \to x=0 $$

$$for \space  x\leq-1  \to 2^{\vert x + 1 \vert} - 2^x = \vert 2^x - 1\vert + 1 \implies x=-2\\2^{-x-1}-2^x=1-2^x+1\\2^{-x-1}=2 \\\to -x-1=1 \to \\x=-2$$